# Clojure app cannot connect to Heroku Postgres with SSL

Tags: postgresql, heroku, jdbc, clojure

I've been trying to make a basic web app in Compojure, hosted on Heroku. I've been following the tutorial on this website:

http://www.vijaykiran.com/2012/01/17/web-application-development-with-clojure-part-2/

and have been grinding away at the Lobos and Korma part for about 2 days now. My app can now connect to my local Postgres server, but when I try to push to Heroku or connect to my Heroku Postgres db, I get the following error:

```
PSQLException FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "the IP", user "the username", database "the dbname", SSL off  org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication (ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
```

Here's my project.clj:

```
(defproject portfolio "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "My personal portfolio"
  :url "the URL"
  :license {:name "FIXME: choose"
            :url "http://example.com/FIXME"}
  :dependencies [[compojure "1.1.1"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.0"]
                 [ring/ring-devel "1.1.0"]
                 [ring-basic-authentication "1.0.1"]
                 [environ "0.4.0"]
                 [com.cemerick/drawbridge "0.0.6"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.4"]
                 [lobos "1.0.0-beta1"]
                 [korma "0.3.0-RC5"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.2.3"]
                 [postgresql "9.1-901.jdbc4"]
                 [clj-yaml "0.3.1"]
                 [http.async.client "0.5.2"]
                 [clj-bonecp-url "0.1.0"]
                 [org.slf4j/slf4j-nop "1.7.2"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :plugins [[environ/environ.lein "0.2.1"]]
  :hooks [environ.leiningen.hooks]
  :profiles {:production {:env {:production true}}})
```

I'm using lobos (https://github.com/budu/lobos) for the data migration. I followed the github page's advice and made a config.clj, which I edited with advice from [this page](http://pupeno.com/2011/08/20/how-to-use-lobos-with-heroku/).

```
(ns lobos.config
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [replace reverse])
  (:use [clojure.string :as str]
        lobos.connectivity)
  (:import (java.net URI)))

(defn heroku-db
  "Generate the db map according to Heroku environment when available."
  []
  (when (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
    (let [url (URI. (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL"))
          host (.getHost url)
          port (if (pos? (.getPort url)) (.getPort url) 5432)
          path (.getPath url)]
      (merge
       {:subname (str "//" host ":" port path)}
       (when-let [user-info (.getUserInfo url)]
         {:user (first (str/split user-info #":"))
          :password (second (str/split user-info #":"))})))))

(def db
  (merge {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
          :subprotocol "postgresql"
          :subname "//localhost:5432/blogdb"}
         (heroku-db)))

(defn open-global-when-necessary
  "Open a global connection only when necessary, that is, when no previous
  connection exist or when db-spec is different to the current global
  connection."
  [db-spec]
  ;; If the connection credentials has changed, close the connection.
  (when (and (@lobos.connectivity/global-connections :default-connection)
             (not= (:db-spec (@lobos.connectivity/global-connections :default-connection)) db-spec))
    (lobos.connectivity/close-global))
  ;; Open a new connection or return the existing one.
  (if (nil? (@lobos.connectivity/global-connections :default-connection))
    ((lobos.connectivity/open-global db-spec) :default-connection)
    (@lobos.connectivity/global-connections :default-connection)))


(open-global-when-necessary db)
```

Which gives me the error I noted above.

I managed to figure out how to enable SSL, but adding `:ssl "true"` to the db map in config.clj. However, now I have a new error:

```
SunCertPathBuilderException unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

When I try to push to heroku, I get the following error, whether SSL is on or off:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections., compiling:(config.clj:44:1)
```

If you need any more specifics, let me know.

Comment: See similar: [Trouble connecting to postgresql DB on Heroku with Korma (Clojure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175655/trouble-connecting-to-postgresql-db-on-heroku-with-korma-clojure)

Answer (score 4):

I had trouble making a simple query to a postgres addon on a heroku instance, too.
A local setup that has a similar setup would not work on the heroku setup.

What I did was to add a **:sslmode "require"** key-value pair to my db-spec map.

e.g. This would be my local db spec that works.

```
(def db-str {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
         :subprotocol "postgresql"
         :subname "//localhost:5432/testdb"
         :user "postgres"
         :password "password"})
```

This would be my heroku db spec.

```
(def db-str {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
         :subprotocol "postgresql"
         :subname "//remotehost:5432/testdb"
         :user "postgres"
         :password "password"
         :sslmode "require"})
```

Notice the :sslmode key and its value.
Without the :sslmode key-value pair, "SunCertPathBuilderException unable to find valid certification path to requested target." will occur.

Comment: i am using a connection string, how do you require sslmode with that?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being the best thing is probably to simply use the `@#'parse-properties-url` trick to work around the fact that the function you need inside clojure.java.jdbc is private.

However, this change should make it easier to turn on SSL in future versions:

https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/pull/35#issuecomment-32956962